# Connecting to MYSQL via XAMP in Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, xampp, wamp

Im trying to connect my Android app with MYSQL via XAMP. Ive been looking for other similar questions but any has really helped me. Ive tried to run the code in the emulator but its giving me problems with DB and other stuff. The table in MYSQL has 2 fields, Sensors and Calibrated (both Strings). cm.GetMobileUnits works fine and returns a Pair with both fields. This is the Android code:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> stringList = cm.getMobileUnits("Mobile Device");
                //Log.d("MYSQL", "Tuplas adquiridas");
                String url="http://192.168.1.10/test.php";

                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

                 List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                 for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); i++) {
                     Pair<String, String> pair = stringList.get(i);
                     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Sensors", pair.first));
                     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Calibrated", pair.second));
                     httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  
                     HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                     httpResponse.getEntity().consumeContent();

                 }
                     } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
                     {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace(); 
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }     
        }
    });
```

And my PHP file:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","1234");
if (!$con)
 {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }

mysql_select_db("eHealthDroid", $con);

$sensors = $_POST['Sensors'];
$calibrated = $_POST['Calibrated'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO mobile_units(sensors,calibrated)values('$sensors', '$calibrated')";
      mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Now I have another question...why do I get differents outputs depending if I use WIFI or 3G on the phone? Which one should I use?

Output with wifi:

```
08-09 12:53:25.178: I/System.out(6926): [socket][0] connection /192.168.1.10:80;LocalPort=46210(0)
08-09 12:53:25.178: I/System.out(6926): [CDS]connect[/192.168.1.10:80] tm:90
08-09 12:53:25.179: D/Posix(6926): [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.pfc.ehealthdroid :80 
08-09 12:53:25.505: I/System.out(6926): [socket][/192.168.1.15:46210]
08-09 12:53:25.505: I/System.out(6926): rx timeout:0
08-09 12:53:25.594: I/System.out(6926): rx timeout:1
08-09 12:53:25.595: I/System.out(6926): [CDS]EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK in Recvfrom
08-09 12:53:25.595: I/System.out(6926): [CDS]read is 0
08-09 12:53:25.595: I/System.out(6926): rx timeout:0
08-09 12:53:25.595: I/System.out(6926): rx timeout:0
08-09 12:53:25.624: I/System.out(6926): rx timeout:1
08-09 12:53:25.625: I/System.out(6926): [CDS]EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK in Recvfrom
.....
```

Output with 3G:

```
08-09 12:56:42.024: I/System.out(7313): [socket][1:49104] exception
08-09 12:56:42.025: I/System.out(7313): [CDS]close[49104]
08-09 12:56:42.025: I/System.out(7313): close [socket][/0.0.0.0:49104]
08-09 12:56:42.025: W/System.err(7313): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /192.168.1.10:80 timed out
08-09 12:56:42.026: W/System.err(7313):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
08-09 12:56:42.026: W/System.err(7313):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
08-09 12:56:42.026: W/System.err(7313):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
08-09 12:56:42.026: W/System.err(7313):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
08-09 12:56:42.026: W/System.err(7313):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:363)
08-09 12:56:42.026: W/System.err(7313):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
08-09 12:56:42.026: W/System.err(7313):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
08-09 12:56:42.027: W/System.err(7313):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
08-09 12:56:42.027: W/System.err(7313):     at com.pfc.ehealthdroid.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:362)
08-09 12:56:42.027: W/System.err(7313):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-09 12:56:42.027: D/dalvikvm(7313): threadid=11: exiting
```

Any help would be great! Thanks

Comment: "gives you problems" - you mean other problems than that your NATted local network using private addresses (192.168.x.x) is obviously not reachable via GPRS/3G?

Comment: Sure, silly question, I didnt think about it. Any idea why it doesnt work with WI-FI?

Comment: By the way, Ive checked the http status code doing 

    httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()

And the result is 404...any idea whats happening?

Comment: Basing in what Ive read, 404 error should be an url problem, right? but the point is I can access to the localhost introducing the url in the mobile phone browser. Strange, not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is embarrasing but at least I found the solution.

I was placing the php file in the directory php/www , being honest I dont know why I thought this was the right directory. I checked the default directory and I found out is httpdocs and...voila!

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand you correctly that 192.168.1.15 is your PC-Localhost with your IDE and you want to connect to through your Androidapp which runs in an emulator? If yes you have to use "10.0.2.2" as IP-Adress. In the emulator that adress is redirected to your pc with the IDE

not connected to the IP thing you also have to allow your app to use the internetconnection:

Comment: No! I want to access to the server from my App which I run in a mobile device. I mentioned the emulator cause sometimes in these cases, people recommend to run the application using the emulator to see if the problem is a programming problem or other kind of problem.